# Json deserializer

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

im currently making my first steep with json and well im complety confused.
I found many examples how to deserialize json files but nothing helps me.

```
{
   "102": {
      "id": 102,
      "name": "cvmember3",
      "profileIconId": 28,
      "revisionDate": 1373593599000,
      "summonerLevel": 1
   },
   "101": {
      "id": 101,
      "name": "IS1ec76a704e9b52",
      "profileIconId": -1,
      "revisionDate": 1355466175000,
      "summonerLevel": 1
   }

}
```

This is the json i object i got, the problem is im to stupid to deseralize it.
What i tried till now:

```
            String name= (string) new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<String, object>>(json)["name"];
```

Im missing the index, and dont know how to add it
anyone, can say me the correct line to deserialize, i has acces to the libary json.net

Comment: You missed generic argument in Deserialize function. Show us the class description you are trying to deserialize into.

Comment: i dint made one, i need one if i only need to get one arttribut?

Comment: Code you showed will not compile.

Comment: it compiles but it throws a exception (ît dont gets an object)

Comment: You are lying , you are using Deserialize<T>(String) signature without generic argument, Code is not compileable.

Comment: evenutally i just misstyped, and this was the right line:
                    String name= (string) new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<String, object>>(json)["name"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want one item from the string (`i only need to get one arttribut`), you can use [NewtonSoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) to fish out the item you need:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

// read from where ever
string jstr = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Temp\\101.json");

JObject js = JObject.Parse(jstr);
var data102 = js["102"]["name"];       // == "cvmember3"

var data101 = js["101"]["name"];           // == "IS1ec76a704e9b52"

Console.WriteLine("Name for 101 is '{0}'", data101.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Name for 102 is '{0}'", data102.ToString());
```

Output:

> Name for 101 is 'IS1ec76a704e9b52'
>   Name for 102 is 'cvmember3'

This is a quick way to get at just one item value but it assumes you know what it looks like and where it is stored.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could define a class for the data you're going to get back and then parse your JSON into a dictionary something like this:

```
public class DataClass
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public int profileIconId;
    public long revisionDate;
    public int summonerLevel;
}
```

Then

```
Dictionary<int, DataClass> myDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, DataClass>>(json);
string foundName = myDictionary[102].name;
```